# The type or namespace name 'ParsingEngine' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.BizTalk'

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2020

I have a BizTalk 2013r2 solution that I'd like to upgrade to run on BizTalk 2020.

I've cloned the repo and opened on a new VM with Visual Studio 2019. It presented the message that is was going update the code. All seems to be ok except for problem resolving the namespace "Microsoft.BizTalk.ParsingEngine". This is when tying to compile a custom pipeline components assembly.

I've decompiled the Microsoft.BizTalk.Pipeline assembly on the old VM and can see it contains the Microsoft.BizTalk.ParsingEngine namespace:

[image]

However, this (and several more) are missing on the new .Net4 version on the new VM:

[image]

Does anyone know where to find Microsoft.BizTalk.ParsingEngine on BizTalk 2020?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that is now in the `Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.Interop` Namespace in `Microsoft.BizTalk.Pipeline.dll`. See [DocumentSpec.Parse(IDataReader) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.biztalk.component.interop.documentspec.parse?view=bts-2020)